# Better incentive to provide feedback on answers

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

Can we find a better way to give an incentive for people to give feedback on the answers to their questions. I'm thinking about a mechanism to help us close the loop. Sure, there is the "accepted answer" check mark. That works well, but I see a lot of questions with several plausible answers but no accepted answer. There are also cases where there isn't one single answer. I assume that most people eventually find a solution to address their question. It would be nice to have a mechanism that gave them a bigger incentive to tell us what worked and therefore help the next person with the same question. Maybe that could be folded in the reputation score. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

I've said this before, but the OP doesn't owe it to anyone to accept an answer. While it would be polite for the OP to accept the answer that they used there's nothing the system can do to force them to accept it. Increasing the amount of rep you gained for accepting an answer could be counter productive, as it could lead to people accepting anything just to get the rep.

The currently highest voted answer is the "accepted" answer as it's what most people agree with. If you think it's not then down-vote it and/or post a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a better solutions to your problem than the ones in the list, post it, you will be voted up.